# Grid items aren't stacking on mobile

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I have a simple css grid with some images as items. But they don't seem to be stacking when the screen size is minimized. I figured the short code on the grid-template rule would take care of this. Any idea what's wrong with the code

```
  .container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 5rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
  justify-items: center;
  align-items: center;
  
}
   
.item{
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 15px;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: pointer;

}

<div class='container'>
 <item> Item 1<item/>
  <item> Item 2<item/>
   <item> Item 3<item/>

<div/>
```

Comment: Your syntax is weird What is <div/> - do you mean </div>? And how are you creating <item> or do you mean class="item"?

Answer (score 0):

HTML code is not correct.

```
<div class='container'>
  <div class="item"> Item 1</div>
  <div class="item"> Item 2</div>
  <div class="item"> Item 3</div>
</div>
```

Fix it and it will work well.

Comment: Hmm, yea its still not stacking while screen reduced

Comment: It stacks for me. Have you used exactly the code given here? In your original code there are some weird terminators like <div/> rather than </div>.